# Swift Recursion/ Class constructors

Tags: swift, recursion

I am writing a Swift program that will solve post script equations. I have two Classes: ExpressionTree, and ExpressionTreeLeaf, which inherits Expression Tree. In the ExpressionTree Class, I need a method that solves the tree. I also need to override that function in the ExpressionTreeLeaf Class to just return the data of the leaf. I'll give some code for context:

ExpressionTree class:

```
class ExpressionTree{
let Left: ExpressionTree?
let Right: ExpressionTree?
let Data: String



// constructor for tree with known left and right
init(Data: String, Left: ExpressionTree? = nil, Right: ExpressionTree? = nil) {
       self.Data = Data
       self.Left = Left
       self.Right = Right
   }

// constructor for tree with only data
init(Data:String){
    self.Data = Data
    self.Left = nil
    self.Right = nil
}


// this method returns double regardless of inputs
func ApplyOp(val1: Double, val2: Double, op:String) -> Double?{
    switch op {
    case "+":
        return val1 + val2
    case "-":
        return val1 - val2
    case "*":
        return val1 * val2
    case "/":
        if( val2 != 0 ){
            return val1 / val2
        }
        else{
            return nil
        }
    default:
        return nil
    }
    
}


func Solve() -> Double{
     return ApplyOp(val1: (Left?.Solve())!, val2: (Right?.Solve())!, op: Data)!
    
}
```

ExpressionTreeLeaf Class:

```
class ExpressionTreeLeaf: ExpressionTree {

init(_ Data: String) {
    super.init(Data: "\(Data)") 
}
 func Solve() -> String {
    return Data
}
```

}

My question is this: While using the debugger, I never seem to go into the ExpressionTreeLeaf constructor. I recursively go into the same solve method, and get error because the parameters are in the wrong place, causing them to be defaulted to 0.0. How to I get the recursive call to go into the ExpressionTreeLeaf class, so that when called, it will return the data of the leaf?
Thank you

EDIT:
here is the method to make the Tree:
expression is in postfix notation

```
func MakeTree(expression: [String]) -> ExpressionTree{


let precedance: [String: Int] = ["+": 1 , "-": 1,  "*": 2,  "/": 2]
var stack: Deque<ExpressionTree> = []
for piece in expression {
    if(isNumber(check: "\(piece)")){
        let tree: ExpressionTreeLeaf = ExpressionTreeLeaf("\(piece)")
        stack.append(tree)
    }
    else if precedance["\(piece)"] != nil{
        let tree1: ExpressionTree = stack.removeLast()
        let tree2: ExpressionTree = stack.removeLast()
        let newTree: ExpressionTree = ExpressionTree(Data: "\(piece)", Left: tree1, Right: tree2)
        stack.append(newTree)
    }
}
return stack.removeLast()
```

}

Comment: Don't start method and variable names with a capital letter please. Some of us just walk away from code that does that.

Comment: ExpressionTree.Solve() and ExpressionTreeLeaf.Solve() return different values. Why are you mixing String and Double?

Comment: Also, you should post the code you are using to construct your tree.

Comment: @matt, I come from a c# background where methods are capitalized.

Comment: @RobC Thanks for pointing that out. I have everything returning a string now. The only problem is that Left?.Solve() and Right?.Solve() returns String? while ApplyOp takes 2 Double parameters and a String parameter

Comment: What String are you passing to MakeTree(expression:)? Also, are you sure that Data isn't supposed to be a Double?

Comment: @RobC the string is the postfix notation of the input from the user. 1+1, would be converted to an array ["1", "1" ,"+"]. I have it as a string because the leaf nodes are numbers, while everything else is an operator

Comment: I would suggest posting a sample string. It's hard to know what you are having trouble with if you don't post the data.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you solved your problem but I would suggest using protocols rather than inheritance. Also, in Swift, value types such as enums and structs are preferred over classes.

First, here are a couple of utils for parsing the expression:

```
extension String {
    var isDigits: Bool {
        onlyConsistsOf(charactersIn: .decimalDigits)
    }
    var isMathOperation: Bool {
        onlyConsistsOf(charactersIn: .init(charactersIn: "+-*/"))
    }
    func onlyConsistsOf(charactersIn set: CharacterSet) -> Bool {
        rangeOfCharacter(from: set.inverted) == nil
    }
}

extension Character {
    var isDigit: Bool {
        String(self).isDigits
    }
    var isMathOperation: Bool {
        String(self).isMathOperation
    }
}
```

Now we can get down to the nitty gritty. Let's start with a protocol:

```
protocol Evaluatable {
    func evaluate() -> Double
}
```

Wether we are dealing with a an operation or an operand we can treat the types the same with protocol conformance. Notice how the `Operand` and `Operation` only store properties that they need. In your implementation your `ExpressionTreeLeaf` inherited from `ExpressionTree` even though it didn't need the `Left` or `Right` properties.

```
struct Operand: Evaluatable {
    let value: Double

    func evaluate() -> Double {
        value
    }
}

struct Operation: Evaluatable {
    let lhs: Evaluatable
    let rhs: Evaluatable
    let op: Character

    private var operation: (Double, Double) -> Double {
        switch op {
        case "+":
            return (+)
        case "-":
            return (-)
        case "*":
            return (*)
        case "/":
            return (/)
        default:
            fatalError("Bad op: \(op)")
        }
    }

    func evaluate() -> Double {
        operation(lhs.evaluate(), rhs.evaluate())
    }
}
```

Now let's create a top-level `Tree` type to store the root component to be evaluated. If you like, you can even make `Tree` conform to `Evaluatable`.

```
struct Tree: Evaluatable {

    let root: Evaluatable

    func evaluate() -> Double {
        root.evaluate()
    }
}
```

This factory method constructs the `Tree` using the same stack-based algorithm you posted. The stack is declared using the protocol we defined so we can store `Operation`s or `Operand`s.

```
enum TreeFactory {
    static func makeTree(fromExpression expression: String) -> Evaluatable {
        var stack: [Evaluatable] = []
        for symbol in expression {
            if symbol.isDigit {
                stack.append(Operand(value: Double(String(symbol)) ?? 0.0))
            } else if symbol.isMathOperation {
                let rhs = stack.removeLast()
                let lhs = stack.removeLast()
                stack.append(Operation(lhs: lhs, rhs: rhs, op: symbol))
            } else {
                stack.removeAll()
                break
            }
        }
        return Tree(root: stack.isEmpty ? Operand(value: .zero) : stack.removeLast())
    }
}
```

Let's conform to `CustomStringConvertible` for debugging purposes:

```
extension Operand: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { "\(value)" }
}

extension Operation: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { "(\(lhs) \(op) \(rhs))" }
}

extension Tree: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { "Tree: \(root) = \(evaluate())" }
}
```

Let's try this out:

```
let expression = "32+32+*3*2+1-2/"
let tree = TreeFactory.makeTree(fromExpression: expression)
print(tree)
```

Which results in:

```
Tree: ((((((3.0 + 2.0) * (3.0 + 2.0)) * 3.0) + 2.0) - 1.0) / 2.0) = 38.0
```

This problem can also be solved using an enum rather than with structs. Here's an alternate solution.

```
indirect enum TreeNode: Evaluatable {
    case operand(Double)
    case operation(Character, TreeNode, TreeNode)
    case root(TreeNode)

    func evaluate() -> Double {
        switch self {
        case .operand(let value):
            return value
        case .operation(let op, let lhs, let rhs):
            switch op {
            case "+":
                return lhs.evaluate() + rhs.evaluate()
            case "-":
                return lhs.evaluate() - rhs.evaluate()
            case "*":
                return lhs.evaluate() * rhs.evaluate()
            case "/":
                return lhs.evaluate() / rhs.evaluate()
            default:
                return .zero
            }
        case .root(let node):
            return node.evaluate()
        }
    }
}
```

Let's make another factory method to create an enum-based tree:

```
extension TreeFactory {
    static func makeNodeTree(fromExpression expression: String) -> Evaluatable {
        var stack: [TreeNode] = []
        for symbol in expression {
            if symbol.isDigit {
                stack.append(.operand(Double(String(symbol)) ?? 0.0))
            } else if symbol.isMathOperation {
                let rhs = stack.removeLast()
                let lhs = stack.removeLast()
                stack.append(.operation(symbol, lhs, rhs))
            } else {
                stack.removeAll()
                break
            }
        }
        return TreeNode.root(stack.isEmpty ? .operand(.zero) : stack.removeLast())
    }
}
```

Let's make our `TreeNode` debug friendly:

```
extension TreeNode: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .operand(let value):
            return "\(value)"
        case .operation(let op, let lhs, let rhs):
            return "(\(lhs) \(op) \(rhs))"
        case .root(let node):
            return "Tree: \(node) = \(evaluate())"
        }
    }
}
```

And now to test it out:

```
let expression = "32+32+*3*2+1-2/"
let nodeTree = TreeFactory.makeNodeTree(fromExpression: expression)
print(nodeTree)
```

Here are the results:

```
Tree: ((((((3.0 + 2.0) * (3.0 + 2.0)) * 3.0) + 2.0) - 1.0) / 2.0) = 38.0
```

Comment: Hey Rob, thank you very much for the detailed explanation and code. I am still learning Swift and I realize I am using strategies that might not be optimal or common in the swift community. I'll definitely be incorporating some of your code into my project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I originally had incorrect return types which was not allowing me to call functions properly.